# Away3D 4.1 performance issues - how to optimise a scene with many identical meshes?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, stage3d, away3d

I have created a simple test using Away3D 4.1 (2500 cubes) but performance is a lot lower than i expected - only 10 FPS.

I assume i am making a noob mistake (being a noob and all) so here are relevant pieces of code:

Lighting:

```
var light1:DirectionalLight = new DirectionalLight();
light1.position = new Vector3D(400, 300, -200);
light1.lookAt(new Vector3D());
light1.color = 0xFFFFFF;
light1.ambient = 0.25;
lightPicker = new StaticLightPicker([light1]);
```

Creating cubes:

```
var material:ColorMaterial = new ColorMaterial(0x999999);
material.lightPicker = lightPicker;
material.specular = 0;
var mesh:Mesh = new Mesh(new CubeGeometry(50, 50, 50), material);

for (var i:uint = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    for (var j:uint = 0; j < 50; j++)
    {
        var cube:Mesh = Mesh(mesh.clone());
        cube.x = 100*(i-25);
        cube.y = 25;
        cube.z = 100*(j-25);
        scene.addChild(cube);
    }
}
```

And the camera:

```
camera = new Camera3D();
camera.position = new Vector3D(0, 1000, -5000);
camera.lookAt(new Vector3D(0, 0, 0));
camera.lens.far = 10000;
```

Stage3D output in Scout shows that there are many calls between each drawTriangles call and my basic understanding tells me that drawTriangle calls should be 'batched'.

I know that some other frameworks have batch methods but i havent been able to find anything related to Away3D.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you should batch your draw calls. I don't have much experience with Away3D but after a quick look through their API reference it seems that [away3d.tools.commands.Merge](http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/tools/commands/Merge.html) should help you to merge all those cubes into one large batched mesh.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Merge (thanks to Varnius for spotting that) is the recommended way to do it with previous versions, but it doesn't work in 4.1 (see [away3d forum thread](http://away3d.com/forum/viewthread/3674/)).

However, user kurono posted a solution in the forum that works (at least for my scenario) so i reproduce it here in case anyone else has the same problem:

```
var material:ColorMaterial = new ColorMaterial(0x999999);
material.lightPicker = lightPicker;
material.specular = 0;
var mesh:Mesh = new Mesh(new CubeGeometry(50, 50, 50));
var meshes:Vector.<Mesh> = new Vector.<Mesh>();
for (var i:uint = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    for (var j:uint = 0; j < 50; j++)
    {
        var cube:Mesh = Mesh(mesh.clone());
        cube.x = 100*(i-25);
        cube.y = 25;
        cube.z = 100*(j-25);
        meshes.push(cube);
    }
}
var bigMesh:Mesh = doMerge(meshes, material);
scene.add(bigMesh);
```

The magic is in the doMerge() method:

```
function doMerge(meshes:Vector.<Mesh>, material:MaterialBase):Mesh
{
    var isub:ISubGeometry;
    var rawVertsAll:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();
    var rawIndicesAll:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>();
    var rawUVsAll:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();
    var rawNormalsAll:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();
    var rawTangentsAll:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();
    var offset:uint = 0;
    var verts:Vector.<Number>;
    var normals:Vector.<Number>;
    var tangents:Vector.<Number>;
    var uvs:Vector.<Number>;
    var indices:Vector.<uint>;
    var i:uint;
    var j:uint;
    var k:uint;
    for (k = 0; k < meshes.length; k++)
    {
        var m:Mesh = meshes[k];
        isub = m.geometry.subGeometries[0].cloneWithSeperateBuffers();
        isub.applyTransformation(m.transform.clone());
        verts = new Vector.<Number>();
        normals = new Vector.<Number>();
        tangents = new Vector.<Number>();
        uvs = new Vector.<Number>();
        indices = isub.indexData;
        for (i = 0; i < isub.numVertices; i++)
        {
            verts.push(isub.vertexData[i * isub.vertexStride + isub.vertexOffset]);
            verts.push(isub.vertexData[i * isub.vertexStride + isub.vertexOffset + 1]);
            verts.push(isub.vertexData[i * isub.vertexStride + isub.vertexOffset + 2]);
            normals.push(isub.vertexNormalData[i * isub.vertexNormalStride + isub.vertexNormalOffset]);
            normals.push(isub.vertexNormalData[i * isub.vertexNormalStride + isub.vertexNormalOffset + 1]);
            normals.push(isub.vertexNormalData[i * isub.vertexNormalStride + isub.vertexNormalOffset + 2]);
            tangents.push(isub.vertexTangentData[i * isub.vertexTangentStride + isub.vertexTangentOffset]);
            tangents.push(isub.vertexTangentData[i * isub.vertexTangentStride + isub.vertexTangentOffset + 1]);
            tangents.push(isub.vertexTangentData[i * isub.vertexTangentStride + isub.vertexTangentOffset + 2]);
            uvs.push(isub.UVData[i * isub.UVStride + isub.UVOffset]);
            uvs.push(isub.UVData[i * isub.UVStride + isub.UVOffset + 1]);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < indices.length; j++)
        {
            indices[j] += offset;
        }
        offset += isub.numVertices;
        rawVertsAll = rawVertsAll.concat(verts);
        rawNormalsAll = rawNormalsAll.concat(normals);
        rawTangentsAll = rawTangentsAll.concat(tangents);
        rawUVsAll = rawUVsAll.concat(uvs);
        rawIndicesAll = rawIndicesAll.concat(indices);
    }
    var geometry:Geometry = new Geometry();
    var subGeometry:SubGeometry = new SubGeometry();
    subGeometry.updateVertexData(rawVertsAll);
    subGeometry.updateIndexData(rawIndicesAll);
    subGeometry.updateUVData(rawUVsAll);
    subGeometry.updateVertexNormalData(rawNormalsAll);
    subGeometry.updateVertexTangentData(rawTangentsAll);
    geometry.subGeometries.push(subGeometry);

    return new Mesh(geometry, material);
}
```

And voila! 10fps becomes 60fps

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting 10 fps in the debug player or the release version?

I ran your code and get 20 fps in the debug player but 50+ fps in the release version.

I tried merging and didn't see any improvements. Plus, if you want to access the individual cubes, merging will make that quite complicated :)[image]

Comment: Good point Jerome - i figured i would get better performance if not using the debugger (maybe 20fps instead of 10) but actually it goes up to 40fps - much more of an effect than i expected. But i would still expect a simple world like this to manage 60fps without too much effort.